# Suppress Print[ ]s?

Tags: printing

I have a complex program that prints out lots of diagnostic/tracing information. Is there some mechanism to evaluate it and suppress all printing? I know I could protect every `Print[ ]` with `If[printswitch, Print[...]]`. But it would be convenient if there were some way to shunt all printing to `/dev/null` rather than to the notebook, or its functional equivalent.

Comment: Do you still want the printed messages to be shunted somewhere else, or are you fine with disposing of them altogether? If it's the second, one hack-ish way would be a construction like `Block[{Print = If[$verbose, Print, Identity]}, (* stuff *)]`.

Comment: @J. M. Disposing altogether is fine. Thanks!

Comment: There might be a cleaner/more canonical way, but it's not coming to me at the moment… :)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke `Block[{sym}, expr]` evaluates `expr` with the definition of `sym` temporarily removed.  This works even if `sym` is a builtin like `Print`.  `Block[{Print}, ...]` makes `Print` behave like any undefined symbol while the body of the `Block` is evaluated.

Comment: @Szabolcs:Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One common way to deal with diagnostic messages is something like this:

Instead of `Print` use some other head of your choosing, e.g. `debugPrint`.

```
f[x_] := (debugPrint["x is ", x]; x^2)
```

Now you can either simply define `debugPrint = Print` to enable messages permanently, or you can do it temporarily in a localized way with

```
Block[{debugPrint = Print}, f[5]]
```

This is both simpler to write and more flexible to manage than *flags* and `If` constructs (as in `If[flag, Print[...]]`).

---

An improvement to the technique is to set

```
SetAttributes[debugPrint, HoldAll]
```

Now when we write `debugPrint[f[x]]`, the argument `f[x]` won't even be computed unless `debugPrint = Print` is set.  This way `debugPrint[ expensiveToComputeFunction[x] ]` won't slow down your functions when debugging is turned off.

Comment: I think I first saw this style used by Brett Champion.

Comment: This is extremely useful, especially the `HoldAll` idea!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke It seems to be used by quite a few internal functions.  Try this:  ``Block[{System`GeoGraphicsDump`geoDebugPrint = Print}, GeoGraphics[]]``.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like you are looking for `Inactivate`:

```
ClearAll[x, y];
Inactivate[
 Print[x = 1];
 Print[y = x + 3];
 y,
 Print]
```

> 4

Comment: Ah, so *that* is the modern approach… :)

Comment: Block[{modern = lazy}, yes this is the modern approach]. Block is much more powerful of course... esp. with @Szabolcs HoldAll observation

Comment: I don't think this works if the `Print`s are in an external script, as in `Inactivate[<<"foo.m",Print]`.

Answer (score 6):

This works for simple things

```
    output = $Output;
    $Output = OpenWrite["/dev/null"]; (*or "NUL" on windows *)
    Print["suppressed"];
    Close[$Output];
    $Output = output;
```

Not sure if it might have some unintended side effects.