# How to programmatically modify a function definition

Tags: functions, programming, core-language, code-generation, code

I would like to know an efficient method (without converting Mathematica Code to strings and string processing) of modifying a function definition programmatically. For example, I would like to tidy up a function's code by removing all Print statements that were introduced for debugging/tracing. What would be the best strategy here? I know there are questions on SE that deal with automatic Mathematica Code generation, but I want something simple, without elaborate parsing rules etc., accomplished perhaps by an application of replacement rules. I have tried to do this myself, but evaluation control presents a big obstacle. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a different way to set up debugging. One could use an unused name, like `dbPrint` instead of print.  Then `dbPrint = Print` turns on debugging and `Unset[dbPrint]` turns it off. You could add `SetAttributes[dbPrint, HoldAllComplete]` so that arguments won't be evaluated when debugging is off.  One could also use `Block[{dbPrint = Print}, myFunc[]]` to temporarily turn on debugging. Some internal functions have debugging hooks like this, which is how I got the idea. You could even use `dbPrint[tag, msg, ...]` so that you could print messages only of class `tag`.

Comment: Michael, I am aware of this trick and I do use it. But what I intend to achieve is, in a sense, to programmatically refactor (if you will) the original code itself, so that when it is delivered to a customer, he does not see the clutter created by 100's of print statements.

Comment: How are you delivering the code?

Comment: So don't you want the Print statements deleted from the notebook? None of the answers modify the notebook. Or do you have a way to generate a notebook for distribution from the internal definition?

Comment: Yes, you are 100% correct (I did not realized this until you pointed it out). But hopefully, the modified definitions could be used to generate the appropriate code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### To operate on notebooks

Let `nb` be the notebook you want to alter obtained with `NotebookGet[]`.  For instance, it could be `nb = NotebookGet[EvaluationNotebook[]]`. Instead of `EvaluationNotebook[]`, you could have something like `First@Select[Notebooks[], Information[#, "FileName"] === "MyProg" &]`.

```
nb /. HoldPattern@RowBox[{
      x___, Optional[";", ";"],
      RowBox[{"Print", "[", ___, "]"}],
      Optional[";", ";"], y___}] :>
   RowBox[{x, y}] // NotebookPut
```

Note: This will not extensively tested.  Like the method below, it may result in errors in the code.  It should work well if each `Print[]` statement occurs in a `CompoundExpression`.

### To operate on definitions in the kernel

The function `cleanup[sym, pat]` will delete all expressions matching `pat` from the definitions of a symbol `sym`.  Use `_Print` to delete `Print` statements.

```
cleanup[sym_Symbol, pat_] := 
 Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[sym] = 
  DeleteCases[Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[sym], pat, Infinity]
```

Deleting `Print[..]` as an argument to something other than `CompoundExpression` may result in errors on execution. For example:

```
DeleteCases[Hold[Module[{}, Print["Hi there!"]]], _Print, 
  Infinity] // ReleaseHold
```

> Module::argmu: Module called with 1 argument; 2 or more arguments are expected.
>
> ```
> (* Module[{}]  *)
> ```

Adding a semicolon, `Module[{}, Print["Hi there!"];]`, prevents the error.

#### Example

Example function to clean up, showing a variety of values (`DownValues`, `SubValues` and `UpValues`):

```
ClearAll[addto];
call : addto[x_, y_] := (Print["main routine called: ", 
    HoldForm[call]]; x + y);
call : addto[x_][y_] := (Print["operator form called: ", 
    HoldForm[call]]; addto[x, y]);
addto /: call : 
   addto[x_] + y_ := (Print["upvalue form called: ", HoldForm[call]]; 
   addto[x, y]);
```

Test:

```
addto[3][4]
```

> operator form called: addto[3][4]
>
> main routine called: addto[3,4]
>
> ```
> (*  7  *)
> ```

```
addto[3] + 5
```

> upvalue form called: 5+addto[3]
>
> main routine called: addto[3,5]
>
> ```
> (*  8  *)
> ```

```
cleanup[addto, _Print]
```

> ```
> (*
> Language`DefinitionList[HoldForm[addto] -> {OwnValues -> {}, 
>    SubValues -> {HoldPattern[call : addto[x_][y_]] :> 
>       CompoundExpression[addto[x, y]]}, 
>    UpValues -> {HoldPattern[call : addto[x_] + y_] :> 
>       CompoundExpression[addto[x, y]]}, 
>    DownValues -> {HoldPattern[call : addto[x_, y_]] :> 
>       CompoundExpression[x + y]}, NValues -> {}, FormatValues -> {}, 
>    DefaultValues -> {}, Messages -> {}, Attributes -> {}}]
> *)
> ```

Test again:

```
addto[3][4]
```

> ```
> (*  7  *)
> ```

```
addto[3] + 5
```

> ```
> (*  8  *)
> ```

Comment: How can I generate code from the new defintion? I want to distribute the refactored code to the client. I surmise it would be simple processing of downvalues right? Could you modify your answer to cater for this, please?

Comment: Also, Micheal, is the Language context documented? What is it about?

Comment: @Iconoclast There is no official docs, but here's what we have on site: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165843/language-documentation-project

Comment: To write a notebook should be a process of writing all the definitions, but I don't know how simple it is.  ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions`` will show you how `PrintDefinitions` does it.  It's a bit more complicated than you need, because it pretties up the result, adding links and tooltips and stripping contexts from the identifiers. I don't think it's an easy thing for me to whip out. -- Also, is it what you want? You and your clients would lose any comments, text and header cells, and so forth that would be in the source notebook.

Comment: Yes indeed, I just checked saving definitions to a notebook. Nothing fancy here. But I lost all comments and code indentation and formatting. sigh! The text and headers I can add manually, but comments and formatting is just too painful to restore manually. Any pointers on how to proceed? It's exasperating that a system as advanced as MATHEMATICA does not have straightforward mechanisms to accomplish this or else I am missing something.

Comment: @Iconoclast Have you tried the notebook editing code I just put at the beginning of my answer?

Comment: oh sorry just saw that now. Let me check it out. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: I just looked into manipulating notebooks from the kernel as expressions. There is extensive functionality documented which is (I think) what I need.

Answer (score 4):

This is my first time wading into metaprogramming in *Mathematica*, so take this with a pinch of salt. I can get the `DownValues` of `myfunction` and strip out the cases of `Print` commands, then build a new function `newfunction` by setting `DownValues` like so:

```
(* any old function will do *)
myfunction[x_, y_] := Module[{p = 0},
  p = x^2 + y^2;
  Print["test1: " <> ToString@p];
  If[p < 1, p = p^2 + 1, p = y - x];
  Print["test2: " <> ToString@p];
  Do[
   Print["blah" <> ToString@i];
   , {i, 3}];
  Return[p]
]

DownValues[newfunction] = ReleaseHold[
   DeleteCases[
     DownValues[myfunction][[1]],
     fn_[___] /; fn === Print, Infinity,
     Heads -> True
     ] /. myfunction -> newfunction
   ];

myfunction[6, 3]
(*
> test1: 45
> test2: -3
> blah1
> blah2
> blah3

returns -3
*)

newfunction[6,3]
(* returns -3 *)
```

You might want to look into ways to suppress `Print` though, because the above technique looks pretty dangerous and will probably go wrong in unexpected ways.
[Suppress Print[ ]s?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89599/72682)

Comment: The "refactoring" part is in `DeleteCases[DownValues[myfunction][[1]], 
 fn_[___] /; fn === Print, Infinity, Heads -> True]` if you want to copy that definition out.

Comment: Thank you flinty for something along the lines of what I tried myself but failed to succeed. You may be right, in that this might lead to unexpected results in the case of more complex expressions and function definitions.

Comment: I am aware of "Suppress Pirint[]s?" question, but I would like to have more than that, i.e., code refactoring as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a real answer... But I failed to format it as a comment. Again.

You're opening a deep can of worms now, called "metaprogramming".

Please search for "metaprogramming" and discover excellent posts by Leonid Shifrin and others.

In your particular case:

```
increment = Function[{x}, Print[x]; x + 1]
```

You can try something like this:

```
increment //. { 
  HoldPattern @ CompoundExpression[a___, _Print, b___] :> 
   CompoundExpression[a, b]}
```

The original increment has a tree representation:

[image]

The result will look like:

[image]

Generally speaking you can use rewrite rules to manipulate the structure of the expression (most of the times you will have to inactivate the expression with 'Hold' and friends)

Comment: Ok, nice. This pretty much serves my purposes. This works for pure functions. How about functions that are defined as modules or blocks?

Comment: If you're diving into this -- you have to read about metaprogramming in Mathematica in general. Sorry, there're really giants and I'm not prepared to stand on their shoulders.

You can start here, for example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/28073#28073